# Query Hangs when NOT IN is used with a SUBQUERY which returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are doing this:

```
SELECT x from d where x not in
(
SELECT xx FROM a
INNER JOIN aa ON a.col = aa.col

UNION
SELECT xx FROM b 
INNER JOIN bb on a.col = bb.col
)
```

When we run sub query separately, it executes in 10 seconds and returns 0 records because one of the tables used in INNER JOIN is blank

But, when we run the entire query, it keeps on running for more than 2 hours and never ends.

When entire query is run, we expect to see all the data from d, but why does the query hangs?

Comment: What's the execution plan?

Comment: A NOT IN-subquery should never return a NULL, add `WHERE xx IS NOT NULL` to both selects.

Comment: Try using NOT EXISTS

Comment: Maybe a typo but the last query in the derived table has `a.col = bb.col` as JOIN condition which should be `b.col = bb.col`. Also it is probably best to use UNION ALL in that query (apart from any other optimizations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the subquery is getting run for every x in d. Try it as a CTE, and if that fails a temp table, to pre-compute the subquery and only then use it to exclude records from x.

```
--CTE:
WITH subq AS
(
SELECT xx FROM a
INNER JOIN aa ON a.col = aa.col

UNION
SELECT xx FROM b 
INNER JOIN bb on a.col = bb.col
)
SELECT x from d left join subq on subq.xx = d.x where subq.xx is null
```

Temp table approach exactly the same, just create a temp table with one row for col xx (i'm not sure what your data types are) and populate it with the subquery.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion worked but I want to know the reason why the query hangs?

Comment: Others have commented about the null values in the subquery - that could be a cause of the hanging. My initial thought was that it's a 10 second subquery, which is huge. If that is getting executed more than once, or as I suspect for every x in d, then the whole query will take an enormous time to run, and will appear to have hung.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT x from d where x not in
(select isnull(xx,'-9999999') from
(
SELECT xx FROM a
INNER JOIN aa ON a.col = aa.col

UNION
SELECT xx FROM b 
INNER JOIN bb on a.col = bb.col
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select x from d 
    where not exists(Select top 1 1 from a inner join aa on a.col = aa.col where d.x = xx)
    and not exists (Select top 1 1 from b inner join bb on a.col = bb.col where d.x = xx)
```